# Ajax autocomplete to populate search box from database

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, autocomplete

I have seen many questions regarding creating a search box using autocomplete. I have not seen any addressing the issue I am having, which is my controller action passes actual json data as a page, instead of on the page. I am using ASP.NET Core and like most suggestions, I am attempting to
`return Json` from the controller action. Here is my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("content")]
    public JsonResult Search(string body)
    {
        var returnObj = _context.Posts.Where(x => x.Body.Contains(body.ToUpperInvariant())
            || x.Title.Contains(body.ToUpperInvariant()))
            .Select(x => new { id = x.Id, title = x.Title, body = x.Body });
        return Json(returnObj);
    }
```

Here is my cshtml and ajax:

```
    <form class="form-inline" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" asp-action="Post.Id" />
        <input type="text" id="Title" placeholder="Search" class="form-control" name="body" />
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" asp-controller="Posts" asp-action="Search"></button>
    </form>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function) {
            $("#Title").autocomplete({
                source: function(request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/posts/content",
                        type":"POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { body: request.term },
                        success: function (data) {
                           response($.map(data, function (val, item)) {
                             return { label: val.Title, val: Title}
                           }));
                        }
                     });
                   }
                });
             });
    </script>
```

The form that I am using along with the ajax are in the Layout.cshtml file. When I leave

```
    asp-controller="Posts" asp-action="Search"
```

in my `<button ... ></button>` tag I am able to hit my controller. When I remove it, I cannot. I assumed that the ajax would allow my form to hit the controller instead of the tag helpers.

My goal is to have data populate the search bar as I type, with data coming from the database estimating the users typing. But instead I get a new page that has json data. Like you get when you just `return Json("");` without ajax. But am I doing wrong? Why is my ajax not getting triggered as expected?

Answer (score 1):

You can change your ajax like below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Title").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/posts/content",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { body: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (val,item) {
                            return {
                                label: val.title,
                                value: val.id
                            };
                        }));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Test Result:

[image]

Comment: I have added multiple different versions in my layout.cshtml and am getting the error, "uncaught type, auto complete not a function". Here are the scripts that I have currenlty

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1/jquery-min.js"></script>`
and also `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` and `<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>`

Comment: I am using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Comment: Yeah I was making progress, I changed it to these and removed a few other `<script` I had and the errors went away but it is still not working. Is it possible it is my html form causing it not to work even though there are no more console errors?

Comment: When I was testing, I found that if I hit a breakpoint, it seems that it won’t work. You can try to cancel the breakpoint and see if it works.

Comment: I mean it is not hitting my controller at all. I do not have a breakpoint in my console or on my ajax at all

Comment: You can try to delete `[Route("content")]`,then in the ajax use `url: "/controllername/search"`